# Some text won't appear when printing in Safari

Tags: html, css, printing, safari

I have a CSS file which takes information from a page and arranges them neatly so that when a user presses the print button on the page, it should print out the information nicely. The information has displayed a sort of like a key value pair i.e. First Name: John Doe.

The problem, however, is that the "First Name:" part or any of the other 'keys', which is under the label element, won't show up when trying to print in Safari. This is not the case for Chrome or Firefox though, which seems to print the page properly.

Having the code like this:

```
label { font-weight: normal; }
```

makes all relevant text appear on Safari, but the labels should be bold.

However, changing it to

```
label { font-weight: bold; }
```

completely makes the label disappear in Safari while making it work fine in other browsers.

If anyone has any idea what may be causing this and how I can fix it, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: It's not really much to go on, but I've added what seems like the relevant code. Hope it helps

Comment: You really should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and reformat your question. No one can help you without relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not specify the

`font-weight: bold;`

if having it normal displays it, but you want it to be **bold**?

Comment: I have tried that. Setting the css to font-weight: bold; makes it work fine on Chrome and Firefox, but makes the label part completely disappear when on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

So interest question, hhmmm. It must be your font not support `bold` wight at all? Do you read spec.?

Or, if is that not so, hmm, have you tried using weight units instead? Like so `600`,`700`,`800`. Hope it will help you.

Or, something can overlap your style, add `!important` to your value